# Transfer contacts icloud to android

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

How to transfer contacts from icloud to lg escape 2 via usb and laptop. FYI,I forgot 4 digit passcode on iphone 4 if that's game changer. Thanks, Pamh

Answer (score 0):

There may be better ways, but here's mine:

- In iCloud contacts select all (or all you want to transfer), then "Export vCard"
- On [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com) (logged in with the same user you use on your Android device) you import the vCard file (More -> Import)
- The Android device should automatically synchronize the freshly imported contacts (this might take a few minutes)
- If synchronization doesn't work, look at the Settings app -> Accounts -> your Google account -> tap on the part with your E-Mail address -> make sure Contacts is active -> select "Synchronize now" from the menu)

Please note that this way, you should now organize your contacts with Google and forget about iCloud Contacts. To synchronize your Apple devices with Google Contacts, have a look at [this page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2753077?hl=en).